# What kind of object is this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object 'obj'. Let's say we don't know where it came from, for a moment.

If I do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I obtain

```
[{"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0},{"foo":102,"bar":1,"foobar":0}]
```

What kind of object is this?

I'm asking for I see two behaviours I can't understand:

1) It seems to be an array of objects (?) so I would expect

```
console.log(obj[0])
```

to return:

```
{"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0},{"foo":102,"bar":1,"foobar":0}
```

instead it returns:

```
{"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0}
```

2) I would expect

```
for (var somevar in obj){ 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(somevar));
}
```

to return

```
first step: {"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0}
second step: {"foo":102,"bar":1,"foobar":0}
```

instead it returns

```
first step: "0"
second step: "1"
```

Can someone explain me the nature of this object and why these two cases (expecially the second) return such results?

Comment: It's an array of objects. I don't see why you would expect that output in the first case.

Comment: You don't seem to understand how arrays work, nor how `for..in` works...

Comment: If you want to get the 2nd case you need to use obj[somevar], somevar in your for loop is the index of the array. The variable "obj" contains an array of objects.

Comment: You can use `for..of` here. It will get you the elements instead of indexes.

Comment: Why would you expect `console.log(obj[0])` to return `{"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0},{"foo":102,"bar":1,"foobar":0}`...?

Comment: yea, if it's a simple array of object why the compiler complain "property lenght does not exists in type{}"? First thing I did was trying to loop it as an array but it doesn't seem to have 'lenght' so how I do loop?

Comment: @SashaGrievus: because typo. Pay more attention and install/configure a spellchecker

Comment: If you have `arr=["a", "b"]`, do you also expect `arr[0]` to be `"a", "b"`?

Comment: `console.log(foo.length);` what is `foo` here?

Comment: @ZUNJAE meaning obj, sorry

Comment: @SashaGrievus: "meaning obj" - this works in javascript. You can try yourself in the browser console right now. But you seem to be using typescript. Maybe its type inferer got confused by something in your code.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much/290704#290704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `obj` is array or objects. It has two objects at index `0` and `1` that is why when you do `console.log(obj[0]);` it gives you only `{"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0}`. Which is the object at index `0`.

For second question, the `for (var somevar in obj)` loops over each key of `obj` and since it is a array data type the keys of the array is always its `index` value. That is why you get `0` and `1` in console. To make that work you need to do `var somevar of obj` in the `for` that will then consider the `value` and not the `key` of `obj` array.

```js
var obj = [{"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0},{"foo":102,"bar":1,"foobar":0}];

for (var somevar of obj){ 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(somevar));
}
```

Comment: You could add that to get the objects in array one should use `of` instead of `in` in the loop.

Comment: if it's a simple array of object why the compiler complain "property lenght does not exists in type{}"? First thing I did was trying to loop it as an array but it doesn't seem to have 'lenght' so how I do loop?

Comment: @SashaGrievus: "so how I do loop" - you can start by spelling `length` correctly.

Comment: @SashaGrievus check the updated answer. You can still use `var somevar of obj` instead of `in`

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal Thank you very much, I got this. Still strange the error about length. If i use "of" instead of "in" the compiler says "Type '{}' is not a matrix type or string :D

Answer (score 2):

For your particular first problem - When we access an array by its index it returns value of that particular index. e.g

```
var first_array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
var secound_array = [{"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0},{"foo":102,"bar":1,"foobar":0}];
```

Syntex to access array data with index is `array_variable[index]`, where index is numeric value. for e.g.

```
first_array[0] // output = A
first_array[2] //output = C
secound_array[0] // output = {"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0}
```

This is your **first problem solution** because you are accessing an element by array index. Index of an array starts from 0.
For your **second problem**, the `for..in` statement iterates with the index, not the value. If I write like below code -

```
for (var somevar in secound_array){ 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(somevar));
}
```

the output is

```
first step: 0
second step: 1
```

If you want output like

```
first step: {"foo":101,"bar":1,"foobar":0}
second step: {"foo":102,"bar":1,"foobar":0}
```

You need to write like below code -

```
for (var somevar of secound_array){ 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(secound_array[somevar])); // here somevar is index of the item
}
```

For more info [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
You can also check [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). e.g.

```
for (let o of secound_array) {
    console.log(o)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To the first question:**

You have two elements in your array:

```js
var obj = 
[
    {"foo": 101, "bar":1, "foobar": 0}, //first element at index 0
    {"foo": 102, "bar":1, "foobar": 0}  //second element at index 1
];

console.log(obj[0]);
```

If you write `console.log(obj[0]);` then you get first element and not 2 elements at once because at index `0` you have only one element. **And this is correct.**

**To the second question:**

```js
var obj = [{"foo": 101, "bar":1, "foobar": 0},{"foo": 102, "bar":1, "foobar": 0}];

for (var somevar in obj){ 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(somevar));
}
```

This put in the console:

> At first step: "0"
>
> At second step: "1"

**And this is correct too.** For your wish you have to use `for of` loop and not `for in` because `for in` gives you the index of an element and not an element like `for of`.

**Check the difference between `for in` and `for of`:**

```js
var arr = [ 3, 5, 7 ];

for(var i in arr) {
    console.log(i); // 0, 1, 2
}

console.log('-----');

for(var i of arr) {
    console.log(i); // 3, 5, 7
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right. But in my case the compiler returns that errors. Probably it's simply impossible to debug this without the full vision of the situation, but it's not possibile to explain or fiddle all. Data are given back by a node.js web service which returns results of a query, then the response is taken by a ionic 3 app, parsed with a JSON.parse and that's when the problem starts. Thank you a lot anyway

Comment: "And the compiler does not complain!" - what compiler? in-browser javascript is not compiled (in the classic sense of the word)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, this is written in topic starter language. ;-)

Comment: @Bharata: buuuut there are clues that they're really using typescript, not javascript. TS _has_ a compiler and may raise these errors. So saying "it works in javascript" is kinda useless, I think.

Comment: @Bharata thank you for the example about for in and for of. Understanding this was really worthy to me :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, OK, you are right! I changed it for you and world peace ! ;-)

Comment: @SashaGrievus, you can not change language in your question after your question was answered according to sites rules. May be this new code from you has some mistakes. But in this case you have to ask a new question because I answered your question correctly. If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer and then write a new question in new post.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects in JavaScript. So that behavior is totally expected. The indices are keys to an array.
So when you do
`console.log(obj[0])`
You simply access the first item in the array
Then in the second case you are simply logging out the stringified keys '0' and '1'